# Storing the current date/time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where users can update their status. Knowing the date/time they posted the status is very important. I create a field in my table and gave it the date time type. 
I am new to working with dates/times. I know the structure for the datetime field is this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

I thought doing this in my INSERT query would work, but It didnt.

```
    $query= "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, story, date, view) VALUES ('$user_id', '$story', 
'date()', '1')";
```

When I check the database table the post is successful, but the datetime reads

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

What can I do to achieve my end result. This whole unix time stamp and stuff with date/time really confuses me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote the mysql function, and you should use `NOW()` instead of `DATE()`.

```
$query= "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, story, date, view) VALUES ('$user_id', '$story', NOW(), '1')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try, this will add the record to the database with the current date and time in the format you posted:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, story, date, view) VALUES ('$user_id', '$story', now(), '1')";
```

EDIT: Posted same time as above.

Comment: Thank you it worked! Now how do I format that datetime when I select it from the database table?

Comment: In what way are you trying to Format it? if you could explain it in a little more detail? im persuming your wanting to format the result of your selection?

Answer (score 0):

Lets tr this:

```
$date_time = NOW();
```

then

```
$query= "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, story, date, view) VALUES ('$user_id', '$story',$date_time, 'My_View')";
```